# Timing issue with injected service in token interceptor and auth guard

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

So I have a need to read a config.json file to get URLs for the auth service which is on AWS. So I created a config service that reads the config file and added it as a provider in app.module. It returns a promise and seems to work great, until I tried to inject that config service into my authentication service. In the constructor of the authentication service it tries to use a url from the config service, but it is undefined at this point. Since the authentication service uses an oidc client, I need this URL in the authentication service constructor. The authentication service is injected into an auth guard and into a token interceptor. I think that is why the config service works well everyplace else, but not here as these get constructed sooner than a normal component.

I have been trying everything I could think of, but nothing seems to get me this URL. I am really hoping there is a smarter developer out there who can help me out.

Here is a StackBlitz to demo the issue. This is a small demo, but I think if someone can solve this, It will solve my issue.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/read-local-json-file-inside-interceptor

I have tried adding a method to check if the config has been loaded and tried to hold processing in the authentication service constructor. I have tried changing the promise to an observable. I have tried reading the config file directly in the authentication service constructor, heck I have tried a dozen things, but these are the ones that I recall since I've worked on this over 3 days already.

Method in the app.module that calls the loadConfig method on my config service.

```
  return () => configService.loadConfig();
}
```

As you can see it is set as a provider

```
 providers: [
    ConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initConfig,
      deps: [
        ConfigService
      ],
      multi: true
    },
```

My config service call to load the file. Again this worked great until I introduced the authentication service.

```
 public loadConfig(): Promise<any> {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get('config.json')
        .toPromise()
        .then(
          res => { // Success
            this.config = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
            resolve();
          }
        );
    });
    return promise;
  }
```

Here is the auth service

```
constructor(@Inject(AuthenticationConfigService)
  private config: AuthenticationConfig,
    private router: Router,
    private configService: ConfigService,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
    const clientSettings = this.getClientSettings(config);
    this.manager = new UserManager(clientSettings);

    this.manager.getUser().then(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });

    this.redirectUrlKey = `redirectUrl:${this.manager.settings.authority}:${this.manager.settings.client_id}`;

    this.hookUpEvents();
  }

 private getClientSettings(config: AuthenticationConfig): UserManagerSettings {
    const url = window.location.origin;

    return {
      authority: this.configService.getAPIRoute('auth'), //this line fails
      // authority: config.authServer, //this line works as it has the url already defined
      client_id: config.clientId,
      redirect_uri: url + '/auth-callback',
      post_logout_redirect_uri: url,
      response_type: 'code',
      scope: config.scope,
      filterProtocolClaims: true,
      loadUserInfo: true,
      silent_redirect_uri: url + '/auth-silent'
    };
  }
```

I just need to be able to hold processing until the config file is loaded and those values are available.

Comment: Anyone? I am still stuck on this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use observable and subscription

```
  private _configStatus = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  public configStatus$ = this._configStatus.asObservable();
```

once config is completely loaded,

```
  this.config = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
  this._configStatus.next(true);
```

subscribe in token interceptor

```
   this.config.configStatus$.subscribe(value => {
      if(value) {console.log(`TokenInterceptor: config value ${config.getConfig()}}`);}
   });
```